# Applying a temporal Gaussian filter to a series of images

Tags: matlab, filter, computer-vision, gaussian, opticalflow

I was wondering how I would go about applying a Gaussian filter between two images in MATLAB. I understand for a spatial Gaussian filter on one image, you would do something like the following:

```
gauss_filter = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 1.5);
processed = imfilter(image, gauss_filter, 'replicate');
```

But the algorithm I am trying to implement for optical flow (from the Trucco and Verri text) describes applying a Gaussian filter with sigma = 1.5 frames across the temporal dimension in a sequence of frames.

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB? I think maybe a 3d Gaussian filter would work, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way of doing this or how I would go about creating/applying such a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store images in [width x height x frames] array and apply filter across 3rd dimention

```
img_array(:,:,1) = img1;
img_array(:,:,2) = img2;
img_array(:,:,3) = img3;
%...
sigma = 1.5;
fsize = 10;
x = linspace(-fsize / 2, fsize / 2, fsize);
gauss = exp(-x .^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
gauss = gaussFilter / sum (gauss); 

for i=1:width
  for j=1:height
    array_filtered(i,j,:) = conv(img_array(i,j,:), gaussFilter, 'same');
  end
end
```

As @s.bandara suggested, you can use `gauss = normpdf(x,0,sigma)` instead of

```
gauss = exp(-x .^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
gauss = gaussFilter / sum (gauss);
```

Comment: +1 `normpdf` may be a good shorthand for generating the filter.